# Django form missing method="post" action=""

Tags: django

Good day,

Using Django 1.11, I have created signin and signup forms.

My signin form is working correctly, but my signup form is using the GET method, not the POST method specified. Using the inspector on the signin form, it just shows . The **method="POST" action="...."** are missing and I cannot see why.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'signin/$', views.sign_in, name='signin'),
    url(r'signup/$', views.sign_up, name='signup'),
    url(r'signout/$', views.sign_out, name='signout'),
]
```

views.py

```
def sign_in(request):
    form = AuthenticationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AuthenticationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.user_cache is not None:
                user = form.user_cache
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(
                        reverse('stb:home')
                    )
                else:
                    messages.error(
                        request,
                        "That user account has been disabled."
                    )
            else:
                messages.error(
                    request,
                    "Username or password is incorrect."
                )
    return render(request, 'stb/signin.html', {'form': form})

def sign_up(request):
    form = UserCreationForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Unpack form values
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            # Create the User record
            user = User(username=username, email=email)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()

            user = authenticate(
                username=username,
                password=password
            )
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(
                request,
                "You're now a user! You've been signed in, too."
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('stb:profile'))
    return render(request, 'stb/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

signup.html:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}{{ block.super }} | Sign Up{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
<div class="grid-30 centered">
    <h2>Sign Up</h2><form>
    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'stb:signup' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input name="username" id="id_username" required="" autofocus=""
           placeholder="User Name" maxlength="150" type="text">
        <input name="email" id="id_email" required=""
           placeholder="Email Address" type="email">
        <input name="password1" required="" id="id_password1"
           placeholder="Password" type="password">
        <input name="password2" required="" id="id_password2"
           placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password">
        <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="Sign Up">
        <a class="button" href="signin.html">Sign In</a>
        <input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Are you using right namespace   stb? Do you see error in console?
Easier to use django login system...

Comment: from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout'),

Comment: What happens when you update action as `action="/signup/"` ?. Looks like your related `urls.py` belongs to another app.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the form assignment in the first line to the else statement of the if ,

Like this,

```
def sign_up(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            user = User(username=username, email=email)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            user = authenticate( username=username, password=password )
            login(request, user)
            messages.success( request, "You're now a user! You've been signed in, too." )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('stb:profile'))
        else:
            return render(request​, 'stb/signup.html', {'errors': form.errors}
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm ()
    return render(request, 'stb/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thanks. The else: is not really necessary as if and when the code hits the return statement, it does not continue any further.